# Syntax error While running python File?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am newbie to python so please ignore if this is stupid. Here, I am getting Invalid syntax while printing the data in some specified format.

```
with open("ip_services.xyz", "w") as handle:
    for service in sorted(...some functionality...)):
        print("ip_server(\"{}\", {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}) # {}, {}".format(
            service.address, service.port, 1 if service.udp else 0,
            service.service_id, service.instance_id,
            service.major_version, service.minor_version,
            service.xyz,
            service.service_name),
              file=handle)
```

Error is like :-

```
  File "producer.py", line 220
    print("{} = \"{}\" # {}".format(signal, value, label), file=handle)
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you are a newbie, probably better to just start with Python3 since that seems to be the code that you maybe copied

Comment: Not copied but need to run some years old written code.

Comment: Well, this `file=handle` syntax is written for Python3 was my point. Python3 was released 8 years ago, so my point still stands